# ILogger injected via constructor for Http trigger functions with Azure Function 2.x

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

`ILogger` can be injected to function parameter, like `Token` method below.

However, the error below occurred when it is injected to constructor parameter `log`.

> [07/03/2019 17:15:17] Executed 'Token' (Failed,
>   Id=4e22b21f-97f0-4ab4-8f51-8651b 09aedc8) [07/03/2019 17:15:17]
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Una ble to
>   resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while
>   attempting to activate 'Functions'.

`ILogger` can be injected to `Token` function parameter below. But the error above occurred when it is injected to constructor parameter `log`.

```
public class Functions
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private IAppSettings _appSettings;
    private ILogger _log;

    public Functions(HttpClient httpClient, IAppSettings appSettings  //working for these two
      , ILogger log  //not working, errors
    )
    {

        _log = log;
    }

    [FunctionName("Token")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Token(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "Token")]
        HttpRequest httpRequest,
        ILogger log)
    {

    }
}
```

Dependence injection below

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IAppSettings, AppSettings>();     
             //builder.Services.AddLogging();  //not working
           //builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILogger>() //not working
        }
}
```

Visual studio 2017

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem as well. I was able to fix it by calling `AddLogging()`:

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IAppSettings, AppSettings>();     
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
        }
}
```

And then, in the Azure Function, I had to do pass a `ILoggerFactory` instead of an `ILogger` and get the `ILogger` instance from the `loggerFactory`:

```
public class Functions
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private IAppSettings _appSettings;
    private ILogger _log;

    public Functions(HttpClient httpClient, IAppSettings appSettings, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Functions>();
    }

    [FunctionName("Token")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Token(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "Token")]
        HttpRequest httpRequest)
    {
           // No need to keep getting the ILogger from the Run method anymore :)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me - but only if i instantiate the `ILogger` with `loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Function.Token.User");`

Comment: You do not have access to the generic version of CreateLogger() ?

Comment: I want to application log events of level debug to a file per function.
Location on disk is`/LogFiles/Application/Functions/Function/TokenFunction/2019-03-11T00-00-00Z-012345abcd.log`.
The Azure Functions framework logs here only if the categoryName starts with `Function.` and appends a suffix of `.User`.
So if i have `[FunctionName("Token")]` and a logger with categoryName `Function.Token.User` i can filter via logging configuration.

`"logging": {
  "logLevel": {
     "fileLoggingMode": "always",
     "Function": "Warning",
    "Function.Token.User": "Debug"
  }
}`

Comment: The generic CreateLogger would create a categoryName `Namespace.ClassName`.

Answer (score 11):

Calling `LogCategories.CreateFunctionUserCategory` fixed my problem. Complete example:

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.7.1158 Commit hash: f2d2a2816e038165826c7409c6d10c0527e8955b)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12438.0
```

**Startup.cs**

> No need to add `builder.Services.AddLogging();` it's imported automatically in the container.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyFunctionsNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyFunctionsNamespace
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyFunkyFunction.cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyFunctionsNamespace
{
    public class MyFunkyFunction
    {
        private readonly IMyService _myService;

        public MyFunkyFunction(IMyService myService)
        {
            _myService = myService;
        }

        [FunctionName("FunkyFunc")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req
            , ILogger log
        )
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            _myService.Do();

            return new OkObjectResult("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

**IMyService.cs**

> Anything in `LogCategories.CreateFunctionUserCategory` will do the job. It seems to be some WebJob legacy requirement.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyFunctionsNamespace
{
    public interface IMyService
    {
        void Do();
    }


    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _log;

        public MyService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            // Important: Call CreateFunctionUserCategory, otherwise log entries might be filtered out
            // I guess it comes from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging
            _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(LogCategories.CreateFunctionUserCategory("Common"));
        }

        public void Do()
        {
            _log.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Hello from MyService");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ```LogCategories.CreateFunctionUserCategory()``` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get away with not using LoggerFactory then you need to change "ILogger log" to "ILogger log".

```
public class Functions
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private IAppSettings _appSettings;
    private ILogger _log;

    public Functions(HttpClient httpClient, IAppSettings appSettings
      , ILogger<Program> log
    )
    {

        _log = log;
    }
}
```