# .Net Azure Function project - How to get reference to the ILogger, writing to the console?

Tags: c#, logging, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function type project in Visual Studio.

This is my Startup:

```
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
        string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("default");

        builder.Services.AddLogging();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<TestClass>();
    }
```

and this is my function:

```
    readonly TestClass testClass;

    public TestFunc(TestClass testClass)
    {
        this.testClass = testClass;
    }

    [FunctionName("TestFunc")]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */99 * * * *"
#if DEBUG
, RunOnStartup = true
#endif
)]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function started.");

        testClass.TestLog();

        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
```

Here log information is written to the console, but in my "TestLog" method (ignore that it looks static, it isn't I just skipped some code):

```
public class TestClass
{
    readonly ILogger logger;

    public TestClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        logger.LogError("asd");
    }

    internal void TestLog()
    {
        logger.LogInformation("test");
    }
}
```

But this produces nothing on the console.

I tried switching "ILogger" for an "ILoggerFactory" like so:

```
    public TestClass(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<TaskSynchronisation>();
        logger.LogError("asd");
    }
```

But to no avail.

How can I get the logger that is logging to the console while I am debugging my function?

Comment: Can you show how `TestClass` is instantiate?

Comment: The ILogger from DI is not (always) the same as the functions logger. You can construct TestClass manually and pass the function logger to it directly

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, I was hoping to avoid that and use DI.

Comment: What would be use of the console logging once functions are deployed and hosted on azure?

Comment: @vernou, by `builder.Services.AddTransient<TestClass>();` in "Configure" method of "Startup".

Comment: @user1672994, I first want to make sure it works in debug and I need to see it on console. I'll prep it for deployment once it ready, not when it's less than halfway there.

Comment: @Tessaract, you show the service declaration, but can you show how TetsClass is injected in the `Run` owner?

Comment: @vernou, whoops, I'm stupid and omitted it, will edit now.

Comment: Can you show the `host.json`?

Comment: @vernou, thanks but the answer by Tiny Wang fixed it. In the default host.json there isn't a "logLevel" key and adding it fixes my problem. -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I misunderstand in some place... ? Although I don't know the reason, but I think I can share my test result:

[image]

My test class:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public interface ICommonUtil
    {
        public string easyTest(string param);
    }

    public class CommonUtil : ICommonUtil
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public CommonUtil(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("CommonUtil");
        }

        public string easyTest(string param)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("this is easy test");
            return param + "asdf";
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
using FunctionApp1;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICommonUtil, CommonUtil>();
        }
    }
}
```

function.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public  class Function1
    {
        private ICommonUtil _util;

        public Function1(ICommonUtil util)
        {
            this._util = util;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            string name = req.Query["name"];
            name = _util.easyTest(name);

            return new OkObjectResult(name);
        }
    }
}
```

And host.json

[image]

Meterials I referred to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55049930

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#registering-services

Comment: Thanks, it was the host.json. The default one doesn't have a "logLevel" key. Adding it fixes my problem. Jesus H. Christ D: